# android:autoLink="phone" how to handle a click?

Tags: android

My layout.xml snippet:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewPhoneValue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:textColorLink="@color/color_blue" />
```

OK. Now phone show as blue link. And when click it's open phone caller. Nice.

I use **android:autoLink="phone"** because it's correct formatted many phone numbers.
Now I need to handle when user click on this link and use my custom handler.
**textViewPhoneValue** can content five phone numbers. I need when click on second phone number to get this number. Is it possible?

Comment: @user8542613 you can remove `autoLink` and just use `View.onClickListener` to handle it

Comment: Not help. See my comment above

Answer (score 1):

The better way would be multiple textView's but if you cannot do that.
You can use spannable text to add multiple click functions

```
String s="Phone1 Phone2 Phone3";
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(s);
    String first =" Phone1";
    String second =" Phone2";
    String third =" Phone3";
    int firstIndex = s.toString().indexOf(first);
    int secondIndex = s.toString().indexOf(second);
    ClickableSpan firstwordClick = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            ///............
        }
    }; 
    ClickableSpan secondwordClick = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            ///............
        }
    }; 
    ss.setSpan(firstwordClick,firstIndex, firstIndex+first.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ss.setSpan(secondwordClick,secondIndex, secondIndex+second.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setLinksClickable(true);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    textView.setText(ss,BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

it's not a good example but you can get the main idea.